# Laravel Horizon Jobs - What exactly is stored in Redis?

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-horizon

If I have a queuable Job class that I've set up to be dispatched and handled through horizon with redis, I have some questions about exactly how redis stores the information for that job.

So, the base case is a job that takes a big string payload - let's just say it's a payload with 1GB of text data

```
Class Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private string $requestInfo;

    public function __construct(requestInfo)
    {
        $this->requestInfo = $requestInfo;
    }
```

Now in this case, if I dispatch the Job with the Payload, I would of course expect the full payload to be stored on Redis -- the full 1GB would be all stored on that redis record.

Now, Imagine instead that I wrote the Payload to a database, and instead just sent the ID of that database record:

```
Class Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private string $requestInfo;

    public function __construct(int $requestInfoId)
    {
        $this->requestInfo = RequestInfo::find($requestInfoId)->info;
    }
```

So I'm still loading the 1GB payload in the constructor function, but I'm only sending the constructor the Integer ID of the database record. In this case, what does Redis store about this job? Does it record only what I need to initiate the job class (the requestInfoId) or does it also record the information I set on the class instance in the Constructor? Is it still storing that 1GB payload in Redis?

Comment: My impression is, 1) will have more payload on the queue, while 2) will have more traffic getting the requestInfo (e.g. from database). So if the full info is already available when the Job is dispatched, it might be better to send the full payload.
In general it seems more elegant to me to pass only the ID and have the constructor deal with the rest.

Comment: The entire job class and it's properties are serialized (`\Illuminate\Queue\Queue::createPayload`) so in your two examples it'll amount to the same thing.

In your example it might be better just to set the `$requestInfoId` part of the job, then in the handler select the data from the database needed to do the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you dispatch a job, your Job instance will be serialized and placed into the store (e.g. Redis in your case). Arguments passed into the job should be serializable (e.g. you cannot pass SimpleXML object there as its not serializable).

Then handler pulls the job from the store, unserialize it and run handle() method.

So, if your job needs a big amount of data to handle inside, it's much better to pass its Id (in your case) and then pull the data **in handler method, not in constructor**.

```
Class Job implements ShouldQueue
{

use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

private int $requestInfoId;

public function __construct(int $requestInfoId)
{
    $this->requestInfoId = $requestInfoId;
}

public function handle()
{
   $requestInfoData = RequestInfo::find($this->requestInfoId)->info;
}
```

In that case only Id will be stored in Redis.

Comment: Thank you, I need to populate the actual data in the handle() method and not in the constructor, got it. Thanks as well @Gavin